# asp.net 2.0 hosting silverlight content using SL plugin - blank page

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, iis, web

We have a webserver called 'development' that runs IIS 6. That very server is part of our local domain pr.local.

That server is hosting asp.net 2.0 app that has page with a silverlight (SL 4.0) component. The component is placed on the page via standard object tag.

IIS 6 has been correctly configured with required MIME types.

When we browse using IE8 to the page we either receive a blank page or we see the silverlight component content correctly. Here are the scenarios:

1. Url: http://development/app/test.aspx (Result: Blank page)
2. Url: http://development.pr.local/app/test.aspx (Result: works)
3. Url: http://192.168.1.1/app/test.aspx (Result: works)
4. Url: http://localhost/app/test.aspx (Result: works)

From the above results the only time it doesn't work is if I use local computer name without qualifying it with local domain name. Any ideas why?

Btw, this problem only occurs in IE,- FireFox, Chrome work fine in all scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that if you don't put single no-breaking-space in td cell where SL control resides, the SL will disappear in IE.

Answer (score 1):

First port of call is use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to see what the actual browser to server conversation looks like.  That is likely to reveal what the variation is between the approaches.